# N Unit Visual Studio 2017 Test Explorer not finding Tests

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, visual-studio-2017, test-explorer

I am writing a selenium Test Framework using NUnit and literally overnight all my tests have vanished from test explorer. I have been on various posts regarding similar issues and have tried the following solutions, none of these have worked.

Deleting the Temp Files- I cleared out all relevant temp files as suggested in multiple places, uninstalled the Nunit packages, closed and reopened visual studio and then reinstalled the packages.

Cleaned and rebuilt my solution several times

tried changing my config from all CPU's to x64 (although it previously worked using all CPU's)

any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated as I really can't figure out what else I can do.

Regards

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Visual Studio seems to have resolved the issue itself literately overnight. Logged back in yesterday and all tests where there, again today still there so whatever caused this seems to have gone away :)